# Heroku infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, twilio

```
  def incoming
    sender = params[:From]
    body = params[:Body]
    @subscription = Subscription.all

    twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      @subscription.each do |subs|
        if (("+1"+(subs.customer.phone_number.to_s)) == sender) && (body.downcase == "unfollow")
          r.Message "You are unsubscribed."
          subs.destroy

        elsif ("+1"+(subs.customer.phone_number.to_s)) == sender)
          r.Message "I don't know that command."

        else


        end
      end

    end
    render xml: twiml.text

  end
```

when I try to deploy the code above to heroku, heroku app crashes.
It works well without this part of the code. 
I looked at the heroku log and looks like its making a infinite loop in this method.
how can I make this into non-infinite loop?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of the Heroku log?

Comment: I checked the logs again and looks like I had an extra '(' . thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved. it was that extra parenthesis.